# What's the difference between With and ReplaceAll?

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching, core-language, scoping

[A wolfram Tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ModularityAndTheNamingOfThings.html#22619) mentions that `ReplaceAll` and `With` are similar:

> The way `With[{x=x0, …}, body]` works is to take `body`, and replace every occurrence of `x`, etc. in it by `x0`, etc. You can think of `With` as a generalization of the `/.` operator, suitable for application to Wolfram Language code instead of other expressions.

Where would they actually behave differently?

Comment: "`ReplaceAll` and `With` are similar."…which part of the tutorial are you refering to? I cannot spot it.

Comment: "With" will rename conflicting local variables, "ReplaceAll" will not.

Comment: "The way With[{x=x0,…},body] works is to take body, and replace every occurrence of x, etc. in it by x0, etc. You can think of With as a generalization of the /. operator, suitable for application to Wolfram Language code instead of other expressions." @xzczd

Answer (score 11):

`With` is a scoping construct, meaning that symbols localized by `With` will be unaffected by whatever value they may have outside of it. Consider:

```
{x} /. x -> 2
```

> {2}

Ok, looks like it did what we want it to. But what if x has a value?

```
x = 3;
{x} /. x -> 2
```

> {2}

Surprisingly, the result is still the same. But beware: the code above does something insidious that's not immediately easy to spot. It's a typical case of the wrong method giving the desired result by accident. Try:

```
x = 3;
{x, 3} /. x -> 2
```

> {2, 2}

See? The replacement didn't replace `x`; it replaced `3`!

`With`, on the other hand does exactly what you think it does:

```
x = 3;
With[{x = 2}, {x, 3}]
```

> {2, 3}

In general, `ReplaceAll` is a double edged-sword: it can be very powerful, but sometimes it's very difficult to understand exactly what it does and it can fail in all sorts of weird and interesting ways. Generally speaking, you should only use it when you really need to or when it's very easy to inspect the result and check that whatever came out is correct.

Answer (score 10):

> The way `With[{x=x0, …}, body]` works is to take `body`, and replace every occurrence of `x`, etc. in it by `x0`, etc. You can think of `With` as a generalization of the `/.` operator, suitable for application to Wolfram Language code instead of other expressions.

> Except for the question of when `x` and `body` are evaluated, `With[{x=x0, …}, body]` works essentially like `body /. x->x0`.

Well, it's surprising to see these statements in the built-in tutorial. **Personally** I think they're confusing (what does "suitable for application to Wolfram Language code instead of other expressions" mean??) and misleading.

Indeed, in the sense that they can both be used for replacing, `With` and `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) are somewhat similar, but besides this, they're so different that I myself won't even try to compare them. Anyway, let me try to list. For the moment, I can recall 5 main differences:

> 1. `With` has the attribute `HoldAll`, but `ReplaceAll` doesn't.

This has actually been mentioned in the 2nd cited paragraph in an elusive manner i.e. "Except for the question of when `x` and `body` are evaluated", and has been illustrated in [Sjoerd Smit's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/298325/1871). I'll add one more example that `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) is more suitable due to the absence of attribute like `HoldAll`, `HoldFirst`, etc.:

```
Clear[a];
expr = a + 1;
expr /. a -> 4
(* 5 *)

With[{a = 4}, expr]
(* 1 + a *)
```

Of course, for those with a good enough understanding for evaluation order of *Mathematica*, attribute like `HoldAll` is not a problem:

```
Clear[a];
With[{a = 4}, expr // Evaluate]
(* 5 *)

a = 123;
Unevaluated[a + 1] /. HoldPattern[a] -> 2
(* 3 *)
```

But these are advanced techniques, and it's more natural to turn to the function that fits your job.

> 2. `With` sometimes renames the variable.

This is mentioned in **Properties & Relations** section of document of `With` and is also mentioned in [Daniel Huber's comment above](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/298319/whats-the-difference-between-with-and-replaceall#comment736820_298319). The documented example is:

```
With[{e = x}, Function[x, e]]
(* Function[x$, x] *)

Function[x, e] /. e :> x
(* Function[x, x] *)
```

BTW, if you insist on using `With` in the above case, here's one possible way:

```
x = 123;
With[{e := x}, Function @@ Unevaluated@{x, e}]    
(* Function[x, x] *)
```

> 3. More general replacement is allowed by `ReplaceAll` (`/.`)

`With` can only replace expression with head `Symbol`, while `/.` is essentially a function for pattern matching, the replacements allowed by `/.` are far more general. A few examples:

```
"a" /. "a" -> 3
(* 3 *)

Subscript[b, 1] /. Subscript[b, 1] -> 2
(* 2 *)

1 + Sin[c] + Cos[d] /. expr_Sin -> "aha"
(* 1 + "aha" + Cos[d] *)

g /. {{g -> first}, {g -> last}}
(* {first, last} *)
```

None of these can be done with `With` in a straightforward manner.

> 4. The performances are different.

Generally, `With` is faster:

```
Clear[a];
With[{a = 1}, a] // RepeatedTiming
(* {2.25736*10^-7, 1} *)

a /. a -> 1 // RepeatedTiming
(* {8.04872*10^-7, 1} *)
```

> 5. `With` is compilable.

When used inside `Compile` **properly**, `With` can be compiled, but `/.` isn't:

```
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]

Compile[x, With[{a = 123}, a + x]] // CompilePrint
```

[image]

```
Compile[x, a + x /. a -> 123] // CompilePrint
```

[image]